# A bug happened when I try to import a "tlb" file. The VS 2013 said that it couldn't find a "tlh" file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, tlb

I am trying to import a file as below:

```
#import "C:/xxxx/Proj/msd60.tlb"
```

But it says to me that it cannot open source file "C:/xxxx/Proj/msd60.tlh"

The tlb file is actually existing in the place where I point it.

In my opinion, the VS can split the tlb file into a tlh file(as a header file) and a tli file(as a cpp file). So something happened and make it cannot create a tlh file? But I don't know what is it. Meanwhile, another cpp in other project can open the "msd60.tlb". So the environment may not exist problems.

How to solve that?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with **msado20.tlb** in VS2015. But I had the same problem in VS2013. After some research, I read that there could be some problem with absolute paths in VS, at it was best to try relative path (which is quite bothering).

In my case, the project is located in a different drive, so the relative path would be really long, so I instead copied the msado20.tlb file to my project folder and build again the solution. In this case, it worked. I know it is more a hack than a solution, but it may help others. The directive looks like this:

```
#import "msado20.tlb" no_namespace rename("EOF", "adoEOF")
```

If someone tries the relative path, it would be interesting to know for sure that it works. Copying the file to my project folder doesn't feel a solution, but a hack

Comment: Still valid for Visual Studio 2019. But instead of copying TLB file I added C:/xxxx/Proj" folder to Additional Include Directories list (C/C++ | General tab in project properties). Surprise, then it worked even with absolute path in #import statement (#import "C:/xxxx/Proj/msd60.tlb").
Most likely, old MSVC bug that never got fixed. I think C++ development tooling is now a low priority in Visual Studio team.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a problem with the property you've set for the MIDL compiler output.
In your project settings use a relative path for the .tlb location rather than an absolute path. Visual Studio has a quirk where it sometimes does not respect absolute paths.

Alternately
If possible try manually creating the .tlb again.

```
REGASM.exe "C:\Pathtoyourdll\your.dll"
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have tried the first solution and it failed again. The second one that I cannot try for the reason that the tub file is not created by myself. It is downloaded from others.. Anyway, really thanks~